# how to quickly download multiple github projects from single author

Tags: git, github, download, bulk

There are github authors with great many little or big projects. How could i download them quickly without clicking every project in my browser, like bulk download?

Answer (score 2):

Use the shell. The command for checking out a repository is `git clone <repourl>`. You can write a loop which runs `git clone` multiple times, once for each element in a list. If the list contains the names of the repositories, then the loop is very simple:

```
for repo in foo bar baz; do git clone git@github.com:username/${repo}.git; done
```

The result will be a clone of each of the named repositories.

Note: I've assumed that you're using the bash shell. Virtually all operating systems use bash by default, but Windows does not. This is why when you install Git on windows you're also installing a bash shell; it's called "Git Bash" in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful: http://www.aheritier.net/clone-all-repositories-from-a-github-organization/

Summarising:

Type either of the following into terminal on OSX
Using ssh:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/googlesamples/repos | ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.load(STDIN.read).each {|repo| %x[git clone #{repo[“ssh_url"]} ]}'
```

using clone url (if you don't have your ssh keys setup or if you have ssh issues) :

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/orgs/googlesamples/repos | ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.load(STDIN.read).each {|repo| %x[git clone #{repo[“clone_url"]} ]}'
```

In the above example, I download all the repositories from the "googlesamples" page (https://github.com/googlesamples).

So you should replace the url with the author's url whose repos you are trying to get.

EDIT:

For more than 30 repositories you must specify the page and number of repos per page:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/googlesamples/repos?page=1&per_page=100
```

EDIT: So to download the first page of 100 repos:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/orgs/googlesamples/repos?page=1&per_page=100' | ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.load(STDIN.read).each {|repo| %x[git clone #{repo["clone_url"]} ]}'
```

While the link I specified above was useful, just visiting the github api pages is worth it..